Airflow scheduler not scheduling jobs but is able to manually trigger DAG runs
I have a docker-compose.yml file that looks like this, and when it starts up, everything looks good. I can visit the webserver page, the scheduler looks good. And I can manually trigger the job.
However, I set a test schedule interval of 1 minute and 15 minutes respectively for 2 DAGs, and after many minutes had gone by, there were no jobs triggered automatically by the scheduler. I am not sure what could've gone wrong.
I am using LocalExecutor, and AIRFLOW__CORE__PARALLELISM is set to 2 to make sure it's not caused by resource constraints. Also I am using apache/airflow:2.9.0 airflow image as base image. My local image is just adding more python dependencies into the image.
Appreciate your help.
The only DAG run was triggered manually
---
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:local}
  # build: .
  env_file:
    - .env
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: LocalExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DEFUALT_TIMEZONE: 'system'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__PARALLELISM: 2
    AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__ENABLE_HEALTH_CHECK: 'true'
    # AIRFLOW_CONFIG: '/opt/airflow/config/airflow.cfg'
  volumes:
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/DataFiles:/opt/airflow/DataFiles
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/airflow.cfg:/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}/webserver_config.py:/opt/airflow/webserver_config.py
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 10s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 5s
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    << : *airflow-common
    command: airflow webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    container_name: airflow_webserver
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-scheduler:
    << : *airflow-common
    command: airflow scheduler
    container_name: airflow_scheduler
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on
      airflow-init:
        condition: service_completed_successfully

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # yamllint disable rule:line-length
    command:
      - -c
      - airflow db migrate
    # yamllint enable rule:line-length
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_MIGRATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
      _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ''
    user: "0:0"
    volumes:
      - ${AIRFLOW_PROJ_DIR:-.}:/sources
    depends_on:
      <<: *airflow-common-depends-on

volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:

I have tried checking resources, logs and no error was found.

From the image that you have shared it is seen that the 2nd DAG is 'Paused'.
You may want to set AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION setting to 'false'
As a good practice, it is recommended to share the relevant code of the DAG as well.
You can also add the is_paused_upon_creation parameter, in the DAG like the below code snippet. This github discussion is also relevant https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/30624#discussioncomment-5604276
with DAG( ,
is_paused_upon_creation=False, 
) as dag:


Hi Subram, thanks for your help. I have enabled the DAG after starting it. Since the DAG can be triggered and run manually, it means that the scheduler and the worker should be running. But not sure why it's triggered automatically.

Hi @HakunaMatata
please share the relevant code of the DAG in your question, especially the args passed to the with DAG statement.
